# Ignore errors in FuturesUnordered

Tags: rust

I have the following setup

```rust
use futures::{
    future,
    stream::{self, Stream, FuturesUnordered},
};
use tokio;

fn foo(futures: FuturesUnordered<impl futures::Future<Output = std::io::Result<impl std::fmt::Binary>>>) {}

fn bar(futures: FuturesUnordered<impl futures::Future<Output = impl std::fmt::Binary>>) {}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let futures: FuturesUnordered<_> = (0..10).map(move |i| async move {
        let mut delay = core::time::Duration::from_secs(rand::Rng::gen_range(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 1..3));
        tokio::time::sleep(delay).await;
        Ok::<i32, std::io::Error>(i) // this line can't be changed
    }).collect();
    
    // this is ok
    foo(futures);
    
    // this will not compile
    bar(futures);
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=4e8e250a9223294b2f1ae2a90f2307e5)

I want to be able to call the `bar` function with `futures`. Given that I can't change how `futures` is initialized, how do I ignore the errors in the stream and only process the elements which are not errors?

There is a similar SO question about this here: [How can I remove or otherwise ignore errors when processing a stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54594292/how-can-i-remove-or-otherwise-ignore-errors-when-processing-a-stream)

But the answer uses `stream::iter_ok` which I think is deprecated or something?
I expected the following to work:

```rust
use futures::{
    future,
    stream::{self, Stream, FuturesUnordered},
    StreamExt,
};
use tokio;

fn foo(futures: FuturesUnordered<impl futures::Future<Output = std::io::Result<impl std::fmt::Binary>>>) {}

async fn bar(futures: FuturesUnordered<impl futures::Future<Output = impl std::fmt::Binary>>) {
    futures.for_each(|n| {
        async move {
            println!("Success on {:b}", n);
        }
    }).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let futures: FuturesUnordered<_> = (0..10).map(move |i| async move {
        let mut delay = core::time::Duration::from_secs(rand::Rng::gen_range(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 1..3));
        tokio::time::sleep(delay).await;
        Ok::<i32, std::io::Error>(i)
    }).collect();
    
    let futures = futures
        .then(|r| future::ok(iter_ok::<_, ()>(r)))
        .flatten();
    
    bar(futures).await;
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7f85502dcae4f86fc52ca74bb40d1f72)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a stream over the successful values of another stream like so:

```rust
use futures::{
    stream::{self, Stream, FuturesUnordered},
    StreamExt,
};
use tokio;

async fn bar(futures: impl Stream<Item = impl std::fmt::Binary>) {
    futures.for_each(|n| {
        async move {
            println!("Success on {:b}", n);
        }
    }).await
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let futures: FuturesUnordered<_> = (0..10).map(move |i| async move {
        let delay = core::time::Duration::from_secs(rand::Rng::gen_range(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 1..3));
        tokio::time::sleep(delay).await;
        Ok::<i32, std::io::Error>(i)
    }).collect();
    
    let futures = futures
        .then(|r| async { stream::iter(r.into_iter()) })
        .flatten();
    
    bar(futures).await;
}
```

Note: since the type returned by `.then()` includes the closure and thus can't be named we have to change the type of `futures` in `bar()`.